# Multiple substitue or replace text in excel using a table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'd like to create a super substitute function in excel (if there is such a thing). For my needs, nesting is insufficient because my substitution list is long.

What I'd like to do is have a named table with two columns for the function to use as a look-up for potential substitutions. The first column would contain the original text and the second would contain the replacement text.

[image: Sample Data]

If we look at the above example, the columns R and S consists of my table, with column R as the original text that I wanted replaced with the equivalent row entry in column S, if found in my list. My data in column V is the list that I want to work on. I want the formula in column W to look at the equivalent entry in column V and lookup in the table for any matches within the text. If there is a match, then I want that text from column R replaced with the text in column S. In some cases there can be 2 matches, as with the top example of 'LHR:JFK' which should ideally get replaced to 'LON:NYC'.

There are ways to do this with VBA but I would like to know if there is an Excel formula option for the same as I don't know where to begin with VBA.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do as you ask:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(V2,LEFT(V2,3),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(V2,3),R:S,2,FALSE),LEFT(V2,3))),RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(V2,LEFT(V2,3),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(V2,3),R:S,2,FALSE),LEFT(V2,3))),3),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(V2,LEFT(V2,3),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(V2,3),R:S,2,FALSE),LEFT(V2,3))),3),R:S,2,FALSE),RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(V2,LEFT(V2,3),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(V2,3),R:S,2,FALSE),LEFT(V2,3))),3)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the formula. It works, but I noticed that when nothing from the lookup table matches, the formula just returns the same value as that in the cell from column V. Is there a way for it to return a blank cell if nothing from the lookup table matches.

For example, 'MAN:AMS' should return a blank cell rather than returning 'MAN:AMS'.

Comment: That specification was not in your original question, or did I miss something?

Comment: No you didn't miss anything. My apologies as I just didn't realise it earlier. With the current formula it replaces one or both the codes in the cell in column V, if matched with the table. I would like to add another bit to it so that when none of the two codes match anything in the table, it should return a blank cell.
Sorry for the extra work. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Then that is a new question, and deserves a new post.  try to figure it out on your own and post your attempts with your question when you get stuck.  It will involve an IF() formula.  This answered your posted question.  Please mark as correct.